# Bring back first card on screen after swiping last card/all cards (flutter)

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter tindercard package. Currently, after swiping all cards, screen goes blank, i.e. it doesn't show any more cards.

But I want to show cards again repeatedly starting from the first card. Kind of loop, where user is presented with first card again after swiping all cards.

Each card has a button, which will take user to a screen (which is same for all cards), so its not about like or dislike thing, if user will click on submit button of any card, swipe card screen will navigate out of current screen. Final action will happen only when user will tap on that submit button, that's why I want this loop of cards.

Checked the documentation, nothing much is written or explained. Checked all the available functions/parameters of the package, no idea how to achieve this functionality.

Maybe something can be done in 'swipeCompleteCallback(CardSwipeOrientation orientation, int index){}', but don't know exactly how. This seems more linked to action related to swipe complete of a individual card.

Answer (score 0):

This is the question you were asking for is [here](https://github.com/ShaunRain/flutter_tindercard/issues/25) on the github issue.